# pyodbc cursor.executemany() (insert) correctly fills the table but finish with the exit code -1073741571

Tags: sql-server, python-3.6, pyodbc, executemany

Enviroment:

1. python-3.6
2. pyodbc-4.0.23
3. mssql server 2014

When I use `cursor.executemany()` with `cursor.fast_executemany = False` to insert data to MSSQL table it works fine, but too slow (about 1h to write ~100000 rows).

When I use `cursor.executemany()` with `cursor.fast_executemany = True` it works fast (about 1m to write the ~100000 rows) and write exactly the same data with the first case but the process finishes with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD) and error `<built-in method executemany of pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x000001DE578AA210> returned a result with an error set` occurs.

The data for an insert has a structure:

[image: data structure]

How can I get the result without having exception?

Comment: You may want to report this as a [pyodbc issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues).

Comment: Thank you for a link. 
I've created an issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/431